# CLI has stopped working, with if isset inside a foreach, using laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

so i really have to do an if isset inside a foreach but everytime i load the url, windows give me **CLI Has Stopped Working** report, and then my artisan serve is close.

here is my controller

```
public function nilairapor($id){

$mapel = DB::table('view_ket')
->where('id_isikelas', $id)
->where('id_tahun', $this->tahun)
->where('id_semester', $this->semester)->groupBy('namamapel')->get();

foreach ($mapel as $getid) {

    if(isset(DB::table('view_sikap')->where('id_isikelas', $id)->where('id_mapel', $getid->id_mapel)->where('id_tahun', $this->tahun)->where('id_semester', $this->semester)->first())){
       $nobserv =  DB::table('view_sikap')
            ->where('id_isikelas', $id)
            ->where('id_mapel', $getid->id_mapel)
            ->where('namanilai', 'Nilai Observasi')
            ->where('id_tahun', $this->tahun)
            ->where('id_semester', $this->semester)->first()->nilai;
        $nds = DB::table('view_sikap')
            ->where('id_isikelas', $id)
            ->where('id_mapel', $getid->id_mapel)
            ->where('namanilai', 'Nilai Diri Sendiri')
            ->where('id_tahun', $this->tahun)
            ->where('id_semester', $this->semester)->first()->nilai;
        $nateman = DB::table('view_sikap')
            ->where('id_isikelas', $id)
            ->where('id_mapel', $getid->id_mapel)
            ->where('namanilai', 'Nilai Antar Teman')
            ->where('id_tahun', $this->tahun)
            ->where('id_semester', $this->semester)->first()->nilai;
        $njurnal = DB::table('view_sikap')
            ->where('id_isikelas', $id)
            ->where('id_mapel', $getid->id_mapel)
            ->where('namanilai', 'Nilai Jurnal')
            ->where('id_tahun', $this->tahun)
            ->where('id_semester', $this->semester)->first()->nilai;

        $nasikap = ($nobserv + $nds + $nateman + $njurnal) / 4;
    }else{
        $nasikap = 0;
    }
    echo $nasikap;
}

}
```

i'm using windows 10, and PHP 5.6.3
May you have a good day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to debug this...

**First** check your logs to find out where the problem actually occurs. Laravel log is under */storage/logs*. It will most definitely tell you where the error occurs.

**Second** why use `isset` with a database query? instead use strict comparison

```
if (DB::table('view_sikap')->,,,->first() !== null) {
```

**finally** if your error prevails, please consider sharing some more information about your system: OS, config-files, PHP version etc.

Comment: ohh thank you very much, it worked!! i got panic when i see CLI has stopped working

Comment: @redwhale21 What worked? If you have found a solution to your problem please mark the answer as 'solved'